# Cosine Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Given the following function
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & 0\leq x\leq1 \\ 1, & 1<x\leq2 \end{array}\right.$$
I have to find its cosine Fourier series. I expanded it in a even way such that
$$2L=4\Rightarrow L=2$$
So,
$$a_{0}=\frac{2}{2}\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx=1$$
and
$$a_{n}=\frac{2}{2}\int_{0}^{2}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)dx=-\frac{2}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

I know $\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)=0$ if $n$ is even, but if $n$ is odd, it will be equal to $-1$ or $1$. My problem is: how can I rewrite this as $(-1)$ power to something? I mean, I tried
$$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)=(-1)^{n}$$
or even
$$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)=(-1)^{2n+1}$$
But I always get $1$.

Comment: sin(nπ/2)=(−1) ^2n+1 looks good to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write what you want is
$$\sin\left(\frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2}\right)=(-1)^m\qquad \text{and}\qquad \sin\left(\frac{2m\pi}{2}\right)=0$$
for any $m\in\mathbb Z$.